# Add reputation to my new account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I have used SO profile([Umesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914184/umesh)) for 2 years and my reputations has crossed 4k+.

Unfortunately, the email ID I used to log in is no longer active. So, I can't use it for logging into Stackoverflow.

Now I want to get my reputation transferred to my account that I have logged in currently.

**Details:**

*Previous SO Account:* [umesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/914184/umesh)
*Current SO Account:* [umesh-patil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2833565/umesh-patil)

I followed the steps given in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) but I couldn't edit "About Me" section of my previous account.  Please advice to merge 2 accounts.

Comment: Did you contact to [the support](http://stackoverflow.com/contact)?

Comment: Tx. Yes. I did contact.

Comment: Then wait for their reply. Since you have the email id of your old account they shall merge both accounts (IIRC).

Comment: Thanks ! I can't access old email id: upatil@cybage.com.

Comment: Just wait for us to get it processed, it won't be long :)

Comment: @TimPost , Hi Tim, When will I get my reputations ?

Comment: @UmeshPatil have you contacted us yet (with enough info for us to figure out which accounts are the ones you own)?

Comment: @TimPost, Cool.. It is done !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to [contact us](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to get this sorted out. Explain that you no longer have access to the email of the original account, and that you've created a new one. We can then verify that you're the owner of both, and merge, which basically just copies your new (working) credentials to the other account, allowing you to login again. You can then remove any defunct login credentials.

Be sure you include:

- Link to your profile *On Stack Overflow* of your old account
- Link to your profile *On Stack Overflow* of the new account
- Tell us everything about the old account that you can which isn't public information. Tell us what the email was, how you logged in, IP addresses that might have been used, your First / Last name, month and day of birth if you provided that in your profile section - anything we can use to make sure you're you.

Then wait for a reply. I see you noted that you did contact us, but if you haven't provided all of the information we'd need - then you might want to fill out the form again to avoid delays.

After that, wait about 24 hours (longer if a weekend) and we'll have it sorted.

Comment: I have contacted with My emailID, domain, Date of Birth. Now you can verify and add reputations to New account.

Comment: Then, I will accept this answer and give Up Vote to you !

Comment: May I also know your email or phone number ?